# Typescript function returntype

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-module-resolution

I have this function declaration inside af module:

```
declare module 'picoapp' {
  export function component(node?: HTMLElement): void
}
```

and then using it like this in a **.ts** file

```
export default component((node: HTMLElement) => {
   // All sorts of TS/JS here
})
```

But VSCode gives me this warning: `Argument of type '(node: HTMLElement) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'HTMLElement'`.

What should the returntype of the function then be?
I'm not returning a value, but just using the node for reference.

Comment: It's nothing to do with the return type. The problem is that your type declaration says `component` expects an HTMLElement and instead you give it *a function*. Should `component` expect a callback? If so, you have to amend the type of it. Should what is now a callback just be an HTML element that is passed in? You have to amend the code.

Comment: ... Waow, I must be sleeping... Thanks ^^
How would it be written to reference a callback, that accepts the HTMLElement as parameter?

Comment: `(node: HTMLElement) => void` assuming the callback doesn't need to return anything. If it does, then `void` is the expected return type. E.g., if you want it to take an HTMLElement and return `true` or `false`, it's `(node: HTMLElement) => boolean`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the usage of your component function is correct, the type should be declared as following where callback can be whatever name you prefer.

```js
declare module 'picoapp' {
    export function component(callback:(node?: HTMLElement)=>void): void
}
```